# Define a SQlite Database whom support login and messages,also data about users

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite

I am building a toy banking-like system.I need some way to store usernames and passwords.Store a little of data about each user like name,address andmore. I want also to enable it to store messages comming from users and show them to other users.Like a facebook wall does

How should I define the SQlITE Tables??

I have a little idea

users table
accounts table
messages table

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't save passwords, ever.

Comment: @xyious I don't know how to planify the database. If I need some id to reference messages. how aan i do this??

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what exactly the question is. Do you need help with database design (google database design tutorial) ? Do you have a problem getting SQLite to work (google sqlite tutorial) ?

Comment: @xyious It is about database design. I am not a english man.I have searched it before under several names but i don't find what i was looking for. Sometimes i belive that i am firewalled by parents from my house. Thanks.

Comment: @xyious I am a hobbyist and a student.I feel good using SQlite because it gets working fast rightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first point, SQLite may not be the most suitable choice, perhaps have a read of [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Here's some sample SQL that may assist you in designing your Database :-

---

### Block 1 - Creating the tables

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS messages;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_reference INTEGER, account_number INTEGER, account_name TEXT, account_balance);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user_number INTEGER, user_name TEXT, user_hash TEXT, user_salt TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sender INTEGER, receiver INTEGER, timestamp INTEGER DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, message_text TEXT);
```

**Notes**

- The first 3 statements delete the tables allowing them to be redefined, you wouldn't normally include them, hence they have been commented out.
- **user_hash and user_salt columns are what are used for user verification storing a password directly is highly insecure**. You should investigate secure methods.

---

### Block 2 - Populating the Users table :-

```
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES(null,7,'James Bond','see hashing','see salt');
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES(null,8,'A N otherAgent','see hashing','see salt');
INSERT INTO "users" VALUES(null,9,'Fred Bloggs','see hashing','see salt');
```

**Notes**

- Adds 3 users
- first value null allows the id to be automatically generated (actually it is just an alias of the automatically generated rowid which is unqiue per row in a table)

### Block 3 - Populating the Accounts table :-

```
INSERT INTO "accounts" VALUES(null,1,1,'Savings Account',125000);
INSERT INTO "accounts" VALUES(null,2,16,'Savings Account',25000);
INSERT INTO "accounts" VALUES(null,3,24,'Extra Special Savings Account',32000);
INSERT INTO "accounts" VALUES(null,1,24,'Daily Account',1234);
INSERT INTO "accounts" VALUES(null,3,63,'Daily Account',-75);
INSERT INTO "accounts" VALUES(null,3,63,'HomeSaver',30000);
```

**Notes**
- The 2nd value 1 for the first insert, 2 for the next etc is what links/associates/relates the account with the user i.e. 1 will be used to point to the user who'd id column is 1.
- Thus user 1 (James Bond) has 2 accounts, user 2 (A N otherAgent) has 1 account, Fred Bloggs has 3.
- The user interface would select the appropriate references and manage the linking of the id's.

### Block 4 - Populating the Messages table :-

```
INSERT INTO "messages" VALUES(null,1,2,null,'Message 1');
INSERT INTO "messages" VALUES(null,1,3,null,'Another message');
INSERT INTO "messages" VALUES(null,3,1,null,'response to Another message');
INSERT INTO "messages" VALUES(null,2,3,null,'message from 2 to 3');
INSERT INTO "messages" VALUES(null,3,2,null,'Message from 3 to 2');
```

**Notes**
- 4th parameter for the timestamp is null letting the DEFAULT value be used, which is the current timestamp (see CREATE above).

### Resultant tables from running the above (ONCE) :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

## Using the data aka a few SELECT's

### Block 5 - As per the comment shows balances per user

```
--Account Balances per user
SELECT user_name, sum(account_balance) 
    FROM accounts 
    LEFT JOIN users ON user_reference = users.id 
    GROUP BY user_reference;
```

**Results in** :-

[image]

- i.e. James Bond has 125000 + 1234 = 126234 etc.

### Block 6 - Shows messages received (no particular order)

```
-- Messages Received
SELECT 'MESSAGE T0: ' || msgreceiver.user_name || '    MESSAGE FROM: ' || msgsender.user_name || ' - SAYING - ' || message_text AS msg
    FROM messages 
    LEFT JOIN users AS msgsender ON  messages.sender = msgsender.id 
    LEFT JOIN users AS msgreceiver ON messages.receiver = msgreceiver.id
    WHERE receiver = 3
```

---

Hopefully that will give you some ideas/pointers to enable you to start designing your database.

[image]

Comment: Let me try. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain me a bit about password hashing and salt?? For C/C++-based programs. I am reading some things on internet but if you have some material let me know

Comment: I also want raw implementation in source code. Explaining me a bit: I am testing my developer skills trying to write and understand whole source code by myself. I am trying to write everything by myself. If I can't, i will choose a library. I have no experience setting libraries. Thanks